# Is power-levelling good early on in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm pretty new to the game, and plan to do something like this - I basically like the Dragonplate Armor so, I was thinking how early in the game can you get it. Through power-levelling (in this case, getting Smithing to Lv100) it can be done at almost any point of the game. So I can just use that Iron Dagger trick to max out smithing, fight some Dragons quickly to get the required Dragon Bones/Plates, and then make my armor.

But I've seen people say that if one levels up their, say, smithing too much without leveling up combat skills (I'm playing a sword-n-shield warrior, so say One-Handed) the enemies will become much harder to handle.

To remedy that, I saw another trick on YT - right after the dragon attack in Helgen, after you get a sword, you can just keep attacking Ralof/Hadvar, Wait to allow them to regain health, and repeat to get your One-Handed up.

So, by doing all this (power-leveling Smithing and One-Handed) I should be able to get the Dragonplate armor after defeating the dragon in Whiterun's watch tower without screwing up myself. My main question is - am I doing anything wrong? If no, well, thanks. If yes, what? And then what would be a good time to start the power-leveling process?

Comment: The iron dagger "trick" is no longer efficient, due to the gains of the smithing skill being related to the value of the item produced/improved.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, yes, it is. Maxing one single skill doesn't affect the difficulty of the game so much. And, as long as the skill is Smithing, you're improving your defense. Additionally, remember that there is a one handed sword trainer in White Run (make use of his services).